# Azure components authentication method

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to get the Azure cosmos db partition range but stuck up with the Authentication method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-partition-key-ranges

The authentication says: type%3dmaster%26ver%3d1.0%26sig%3dEConYmRgDExu6q%2bZ8GjfUGOH0AcOx%2behkancw3LsGQ8%3d

Can anyone explain me about this authentication type and how to generate this authentication for the API request.

Thanks
Sathya

Comment: Please share the code you have written. You can read about creating authorization header here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a token for every request to get/post information from/to cosmos DB Rest API. I wrote about this in my post by using PostMan. I hope that helps.
https://h-savran.blogspot.com/2019/02/cosmos-db-rest-api-with-postman.html

Comment: Thankyou Hasan for sharing this, I will check this out and let you know the result